# R Boxplot from CSV File

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a box plot from the following CSV file:

[CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP2JU.png)

Here are the commands I use to create:

```
x <- read.csv("sean.csv",header=T,sep=",")
boxplot(x)
```

However this is my output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiYMA.png)

Where is the X coming from and why is the first entry so visually different than the rest? Thanks.

Solution: changed to

```
x <- read.csv("sean.csv",header=T,sep=",", row.names = 1)
```

Comment: i suspect the column 1 which contains serial numbers 1 through 12 is being read as a variable and being plotted. Since it doesn't have a column header - 'X' is being appended to the colname. Try adding `row.names = 1` to the read.csv arguments. `x <- read.csv("sean.csv",header=T,sep=",", row.names = 1)`

Comment: @vagabond This did the trick, thank you very much.

Comment: You can also add `check.names=FALSE` to remove the "X"